# Android - how to add a dynamic image to activity

Tags: android, image, photo

I currently have an activity that does not have an xml layout file. All items are added when needed. I am not in need to add a image to it and it doesnt seem to do anything...

```
         ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
         iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
         Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Pics/Pic_1.jpg");
         iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
         ll.addView(iv);
```

The image is in the correct folder...11 at the end is the Linear view i am adding the image view too...am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use debugger to see if image is loaded correctly.
And have you tried to set layout params on that ImageView. Because in your case it wouldn't take any space (I think). Try something like:

```
ll.addView(iv, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Or use exact sizes instead of LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT

Comment: thanks i used iv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

Comment: I can't really tell you much, because I don't know what your layout is.
What exactly is too beig? The space that iv takes, or the scale of the image itself?
To beat the problems with laying out components in linearlayout, you can introduce weights system in it. For example, 2 views with the weight of 1 will take a half of the remaining space each.

Comment: iv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300,350)); .....that works, just the image is to the left of the screen